# Using phantomjs to simulate click

Tags: phantomjs

I try simulate click with phantomjs with this code, but not work:

```
var page = require('webpage').create
(   {   viewportSize:
        {
            width: 1600,height: 900
        },
        settings:
        {
            userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
            javascriptEnabled:'true',
            loadImages:'false'
        }
    }
);
var fs = require('fs');

console.log('Console-1');

page.onLoadStarted = function()
{
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log('Console-2');
};
page.onLoadFinished = function()
{
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log('Console-3');
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg)
{
    console.log(msg);
};
page.open("https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.example.com", function(status)
{   page.evaluate(function(){ page.sendEvent('click',350,33,button='left');});
    setTimeout(5000);

});
```

I can see my mistake, and i dont know if that is possible, i need any tip for continue...

Comment: How does it "not work": crash, error message, freeze, unexpected behavior, or horde of locusts?

Comment: Just stop with follow steps: `1,2,3,1,2` and stop but not finish